# Holoviews Heatmap specify color for each point

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bokeh, holoviews

I'm trying to generate a Heatmap in Holoviews with custom color values for each point, in order to specify different alpha color values.

Currently I'm generating two Holoviews plots with different alpha values and overlay them like so:

```
data = pd.DataFrame([(i, 97+j,  i*j) for i in range(5) for j in range(5)], 
                columns=['x', 'y', 'val'])
data_filtered = data[(data.x < 3) & (data.y < 100)]

hm_opts = dict(kdims=['x', 'y'], vdims=['val'])
hm = hv.HeatMap(data, **hm_opts).opts(alpha=0.5)
hm_filtered = hv.HeatMap(data_filtered, **hm_opts).opts()
hm * hm_filtered
```

[image: Plot]

This however, gives me a Holoviews Overlay object, where I'd like to have a single HeatMap object instead.

My idea was to map each x/y coordinate to a specific color value in hex form, which has the needed alpha already calculated into it. My DataFrame would therefore look something like this (example):

```
    x    y  val    color
0   0   97    0  #00FF00
1   0   98    0  #00FF00
2   0   99    0  #00FF00
...
22  4   99    8  #FFD29F
23  4  100   12  #FFB89F
24  4  101   16  #D3AFF4
```

Is there a way to tell Holoviews to use these colors?
When I pass the list of colors to the "cmap" parameter it interpretes it as color intervals, passing the name of the column raises an error as it cannot find the specified cmap.

When I pass the list to the "color" parameter, the plot is not displayed at all anymore in the Jupyter Notebook.

### Edit

I found a way to get what I want using the Bokeh library directly. Bokeh is also the backend I'm using with Holviews. This is the code and the resulting plot.

```
source = ColumnDataSource(
    data=data
)
x_unique = data['x'].unique()
y_unique = data['y'].unique()
min_width = 110
min_height = 80
width = min_width + 25 * len(x_unique)
height = min_height + 25 * len(y_unique)
x_rect_width = 0.90
y_rect_width = 0.90
plot = figure(
    plot_width=width,
    plot_height=height,
    title='',
    x_range=FactorRange(*x_unique),
    y_range=FactorRange(*y_unique),
    x_axis_label='x',
    y_axis_label='y',
)
plot.rect('x', 'y', height=y_rect_width, width=x_rect_width, source=source, color='color')
plot.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
plot.ygrid.grid_line_color = None

show(plot)
```

[image: Plot2]

Bokeh allows to pass the color column name to the 'color' parameter of the rect function.
Anyway, I'd still love to have it as a Holoviews container, so that I can combine it and build interactive apps on top of it.

### Solution

With the help of the answer of @thomas-pedot I was able to find a solution which looks like what I was looking for:

```
data = pd.DataFrame([(i, 97+j,  i*j) for i in range(5) for j in range(5)], 
                    columns=['x', 'y', 'val'])
data = data.assign(alpha=((data.x < 3) & (data.y < 100)).replace({True: 1.0, False: 3/8}))
red = '#FF0000'
yellow = '#FFFF00'
green = '#00FF00'
blue_violet = '#8A2BE2'
max_cout = data.loc[:, column].max()
levels = [0, 1, max_cout / 2, max_cout - 1, max_cout]
colors = [green, yellow, red, blue_violet]
hm_opts = dict(kdims=['x', 'y'], vdims=['val', 'alpha'])
hm = hv.HeatMap(data, **hm_opts).opts(
  alpha=hv.dim('alpha'), 
  color_levels=levels, 
  cmap=colors)
hm
```

[image: Solution]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not easy... I try a lot of different converting to rgba then back to HEX cmap without success but !

Make it with style
http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Style_Mapping.html

```
data = pd.DataFrame([(i, 97+j,  i*j) for i in range(5) for j in range(5)], 
                columns=['x', 'y', 'val'])
data['a_new'] = 0.5
# Make a mask of you filter
mask = (data.x < 3) & (data.y < 100)

# Add it to a column
data1.loc[mask, 'a_new'] = 1.0 

#Add the new column to a new dimension
hm_opts_new = dict(kdims=['x', 'y'], vdims=['val','a_new'])

#Enjoy ? I hope... set the alpha option depends on your new column

hv.HeatMap(data1, **hm_opts_new).opts(opts.HeatMap(tools=['hover'], alpha=dim('a_new')))
```

Comment: This is very nice. I didn't know you could pass a dimension name to the alpha argument. So now I only need to adjust my base colors to match the once I had in my custom color mapping. This way I don't even have to specify the colors per point directly.

Comment: I could edit my question but I cannot answer yet, as I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: I edited my question and will mark this answer as solution. Thanks so much @thomas-pedot!

Comment: Thanks, @iRave. Interestingly, it worked great when I followed your example and used `hv.HeatMap(ds...)` where ds is an Xarray dataset, but `ds.hvplot(...kind='heatmap')` gave a `vdims option not found for image plot` warning.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd
import holoviews as hv 
import matplotlib as mpl
hv.extension('matplotlib')

data = pd.DataFrame([(i, 97+j,  i*j) for i in range(5) for j in range(5)], 
                columns=['x', 'y', 'val'])
data_filtered = data[(data.x < 3) & (data.y < 100)]

cmap1 = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['#00FF00', '#FFB89F', '#D3AFF4'])
hm_opts = dict(kdims=['x', 'y'], vdims=['val'])
hm = hv.HeatMap(data, **hm_opts).opts(alpha=0.5, cmap=cmap1)
```

results:

[image: results]

I added the line `cmap1 = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['#00FF00', '#FFB89F', '#D3AFF4'])` which allows you to specifiy which colors you want. If you update it to a list of colors (a list in range of your whole heatmap) then it will be exactly as you want. I guess you can work with `df["color"]` in your case (maybe directly convert to list first, but it will be alright)

Notice I also added `cmap=cmap1` param to heatmap' `opt`.

I assume you work with matplotlib in background, since you didn't specify otherwise.

Comment: Thanks @Roim for this answer. I've encountered a similar problem, but have been unable to adapt your solution for working with bokeh instead of matplotlib. I thought it would be fairly straighforward e.g. with `bokeh.models.LinearColorMapper()` or `bokeh.models.CategoricalColorMapper()` but have not been able to get hvplot to accept them as valid color maps.

Comment: I can't seem to work with that either on bokeh. I think there is a good chance it's a small bug... I'll have to dig deeper into that to give a good answer

Comment: @Roim could you explain how you managed to add data values/labels to the heat map ? Thanks